# Can wtforms be used to validate GET parameters?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have a set of GET parameters that I want to validate. Can I use WTFORMS for that purpose? All examples I find are of POST requests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass `request.args` instead of `request.form` when instantiating the form.  They both use the same data structure, but `args` contains query args instead of form data.

```
form = MyForm(request.args)
```

Flask-WTF will pass `form` if nothing is specified, but you can still override it by passing `args`.